# issue in calling UPDATE api retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a issue in calling update API, when i call api it's show success Toast message but execution is break from `call.enqueue` method i don't know where i mistake.

This is my Api url

**My Url**

https://56aba649.ngrok.io/api/update

**My Interface class**

```
public interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("update")
        Call<Message> updateUser( @Field("id") String id,
                               @Field("username") String username,
                               @Field("email") String email,
                               @Field("password") String password);
    }
```

**My Model Class**

```
public class user {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String  id;
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;

public user(String  id, String username, String email, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public String  getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setId(String  id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

when i debug code it's going till `call.enqueue(new Callback<Message>()` this line after this line execution is break,

but **Sucess Toast message** is printed i don't know how it will success message without calling successfully

**MainActivity class**

```
private void updateUser(){

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Updating...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String   id = (ed1.getText().toString().trim());
        String email = ed2.getText().toString().trim();
        String username = ed3.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = ed4.getText().toString().trim();


        Api service = RetroClient.getApiService();

 user usr = new user(id,email,username,password);
 Call<Message> call = service.updateUser(
            usr.getId(),
            usr.getUsername(),
            usr.getEmail(),
            usr.getPassword());

 call.enqueue(new Callback<Message>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Message> call, Response<Message> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Sucess",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
          @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Message> call, Throwable t) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
        });
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == btn1){

            updateUser();
        }
}
```

Comment: can you post your request format how server takes the request?

Comment: Also, while at it what is exactly the problem here? Enqueue is a Async method, meaning execution is offloaded to separate thread, not main one. What, probably, is happening, is you see a message about success as you should. Otherwise, please provide more info about _errors_ you get.

Comment: server response `200OK` but result is same not updated record

Comment: @TheStrikeBone Exactly issue is when i call Update api Toast message Success is printed but result is not updated this is my exactly issue  result is not updated

Comment: i think you should try your APIs in such cases using postman or similar rest clients

Comment: @aasifghanchi So, everything is okay, how exactly record should be updated? this code do not show anything that has to do with record updates. In the end, on success will only dissmiss some progress dialog and show toast. I think you should look into your backend implementation.

Comment: @TheStrikeBone thanku, i will

Comment: @Shishram API working fine in postman

Comment: post your error log from logcat, please.